# How prepare simple crud java project for git

Tags: java, mysql, git

I have simple CRUD project based on MySQL with prepared tables. But I can't figure out how to prepare my project for git. Which files should I add? SQL script? DB file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want track your sql scripts with java code, you should prepare and place scripts somewhere in your project folder. After you should init git repository in your project folder, add remote repository and push all files.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want prepare project for ready-to-go state. In case of Android apps, for example, it is quite easy. But I'm not sure how to make it  with web app with use of DB

Comment: This requirement depends on how many developers make changes to DB and is there any reason to track changes of DB structure.